# selectizeInput outputs as series of numbers without commas

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I create shiny app, where user can choose few names of security from `selectizeInput`, `multiple = TRUE`.

As an outputs I got IDnumbers e.g: 12276 12277 12274

And I need: 12276, 12277, 12274 with commas.

I don't know that outputs from selectizeInput are always as series without commas.

Comment: `selectizeInput` returns a vector, which you can then collapse into one character string by `paste(input$sel, collapse = ", ")`.

Comment: Thanks K. Rohde :)